# stay authenticated php youtube application Youtube API

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I'm building an php application which receives videoID's from youtube.
but if i authenticate the application with the youtube account it displays the upload videos correctly. If i remove the session or try an other browser it is required to authenticate the application again.

here is my source:
http://pastebin.com/7GezyHZs 

my client_secrets.son looks like:

```
 {
  "web": {
    "client_id": "clientID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "CLientsecret",
    "redirect_uris": ["https://localhost/oauth2callback.php"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

(credentials removed)

my oauth2callback.php looks like:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

is it possible to authenticate with google for ever?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: request offline access and save the refresh token you will be able to use that to get a new access token.   Refresh token will continue to work as long as its not revoked.

Comment: how to save the token properly?

Comment: If the session is not persistent enough, you will have to use database or a file.